# Coldfusion - add list param not correctly inserting value

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-10, cfml

I'm trying to do the following:

```
sentence = "some set of words";
words = sentence .split(" "); 
qryWords = new Query();
qryWords .setSQL("
    SELECT    
        [word]

    FROM 
        [word_list]

    WHERE
        [word] IN ( :wordsToCheck )
");

qryWords.addParam( name="wordsToCheck", value = words, CFSQLTYPE="CF_SQL_VARCHAR", list="true" );
qryWordsResult = qryWords.execute();
```

I'm getting 0 results but no error, where I'm expecting there to be results (and I've checked this by replacing the sql parameter with a static string).  The odd thing is when I dump `qryWordsResult`, it shows

```
SQLPARAMETERS   
array
1   [Ljava.lang.String;@3a4b8277
```

But if I were to do the same thing using tags and `<cfqueryparam ...`, the resulting dump is

```
SQLPARAMETERS   
array
1   words
```

Comment: Is `word_list` a table or a query object for a Query of Query?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> This does work but using the array works in `<cfqueryparam ..>` so I'm wondering why [`addParam()`] doesn't exhibit the same
>   behavior

It only *appears* to work. Since the cfqueryparam is expecting a string, CF silently converts the array into a string (i.e. the literal string `[Ljava.lang.String;@3a4b8277`). So although the query executes successfully, that string obviously won't match any of the values in "word" column.

IMO using [QueryExecute()](https://cfdocs.org/queryexecute) is simpler than `Query.cfc`. Using a placeholder `?`, should do the trick.

*Note, the addition of the "separator" attribute to change the list delimiter to a space.*

```
result = queryExecute(
 " SELECT [word] FROM   [word_list] WHERE  [word] IN ( ? )"
 , [ { value="some set of words"
      , cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar"
      , list=true
      , separator=" " } 
   ]
 , {datasource="YourDataSource"}
);
writeDump( result );
```

Comment: I think `QueryExecute()` was introduced in CF11. It would be much preferable, but I don't think it can be used in CF10.

Comment: (**Update**) True. I overlooked the CF10 tag ;-) In that case, I'd try the same positional placeholder approach with Query() to see if it works. If not, I'd go with building the dynamic string instead.

Comment: How would the `?` placeholder be different than the named param? Doesn't the placeholder simply indicate the order to use the passed arguments? Or does it do something else, too?

Comment: (Update) Get out of my head! :-P  I was just thinking the same thing... Actually it doesn't make any difference here.  I just retested (using your new example as a base) and it must have been a mistake in my earlier tests, because it works the same.

Answer (score 3):

Since you are using ColdFusion 10, you'll be limited in what you can do. But `split()` is a JAVA function, and not CF, so it doesn't really create a CF array of your split string. It creates a JAVA array, which is slightly different. What you want to do is use CF functions to change the delimiters of your string (which are " "). I don't thing `cfqueryparam` will interpret empty strings as delimiters in your string unless you tell it so.

Second, it gets a bit odd when you are running `Query()`. That will run in its own context and not the context of the page. So if your `FROM word_list` is pointing to a query object from earlier in the page, you'll have to inject that query object into `Query()` [`new Query ( word_list = word_list )`]. For future readers using CF11+, you can use `QueryExecute()`.

After you change the delims, you can just use that variable as the `value` of your `addParam()`. Or even better, don't worry about changing the delims and just specify a `separator=" "` argument in your `addParam()`. One other note about `cfqueryparam` arguments and using `list="true"` is that it will do a bit of magic depending on your datatype, like quoting your values if it's a varchar type. Pretty cool stuff.

Anyway:

```
<cfscript>

    /**********SIMULATED TABLE**********/
    word_list = queryNew(
        "id, word",
        "integer, varchar",
        [
          { "id": 1, "word": "notit" } ,
          { "id": 2, "word": "set" } ,
          { "id": 3, "word": "notit" } ,
          { "id": 4, "word": "of" } ,
          { "id": 5, "word": "notit" } ,
          { "id": 6, "word": "notitsome" } ,
          { "id": 7, "word": "notit" } ,
          { "id": 8, "word": "some" } ,
          { "id": 9, "word": "words" }
        ]
    ) ;
    /**********SIMULATED TABLE**********/
    //writeDump(word_list) ;


    sentence = "some set of words";
    words = sentence; //listChangeDelims(sentence, ",", " ") ;  

    /// If using CF11+, use QueryExecute() instead of new Query()    
    qryWords = new Query( word_list = word_list ) ; /// The QoQ object is injected into Query.cfc
      qryWords
        .setSQL("SELECT word FROM word_list WHERE word IN ( :wordsToCheck )") 
        .setDBType("query")   /// Just for Query Of Query. 
        //.setDatasource("myDSN") 
        .addParam( name="wordsToCheck", value=words, CFSQLTYPE="CF_SQL_VARCHAR", list="true", separator=" ") ;

    qryWordsResult = qryWords.execute().getResult() ;


    writeDump(qryWordsResult) ;

</cfscript>
```

I couldn't get my TryCF.com code to save, but you should be able to copy/paste and run it. The first half of it is just creating a fake query object to run the ultimate query against. If `word_list` is an actual table in your datasource and this isn't a Query of Query, you can ignore the parts that apply to QoQ. I injected my `word_list` query object into `Query()`, and everything else is pretty standard. For your `cfqueryparam` or `addParam()`, I added the `separator=" "` argument to process your original string with `space` delimiters instead of commas. I don't know how you use the results, but that should give them to you in the format of `qryWordsResult.word`.

Comment: Ah, good catch. For some reason I thought named parameters didn't work here, but I just retested and they do. The named parameter is much clearer!

Comment: It's one of those fun cases where _OFFICIALLY_ named parameters were added in CF2018, but _TECHNICALLY_ there were some functions that already accepted named parameters. :-)

Comment: Oops, thanks for the spellcheck. I was wondering why the misspelling ran on TryCF, but when I looked at what I ran, I spelled it right there. :-S

Comment: Heh.. I know the feeling.  I noticed it only because I ran the code trying to figure out why named parameters worked for you, but not in my earlier code . I must have had my own typo in there some where ;-)

Comment: Funny thing is I usually try to be very precise on spelling. I can't tell you how many times I've made a `varible` and wondered why my `variable` is undefined. :-)

Comment: Don't know what you're talking about. My `varialbes` are always defined.